# Server distinction among deleting and preserving an input type file

Tags: php, mysql

I am using an input file type inside a form:

```
<input name="upfile"  id="upfile" type="file" >
```

through which I am uploading images to a MySQL BLOB field of STUDENTS table. So far so good. With another php file I am retrieving and presenting in a form, data from STUDENTS and the user has the possibility of directly changing some of this data and sending it back to STUDENTS.

In case the user uploads (client side) a new image inside "upfile" , I can manipulate it (server side) with $_FILES array. In case the user removes(client side) the existing image,  $_FILES has no content at all. However, the same happens in case the user does nothing with the existing image; $_FILES has no content again.

My problem is I cannot find a way to distinguish among erasing the existing image and doing nothing with it, since in both cases $_FILES has no content. So, how the server will know if the user preserves or deletes the existing image as to act correctly?

Thank you very much

Comment: How does your UX distinguish between these two cases?

Answer (score 1):

How does the user know if they are deleting or not-changing the image? Give them a "delete image" checkbox or something so that they, and you, will know what should happen.

Comment: Yes, this is a UX issue. Your UX should correctly convey to the user (AND to the server) exactly what action is being taken by the user, so that the server can fulfill the request.